# Is there any limitation in comparing the timestamp to check the bound?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a subset of dataframe according to range of timestamp, but I m getting TypeError

```
"Vehicle ID","Frame ID","Total Frames","Global Time","Local X","Local Y","Global X","Global Y","V_Len","V_Width","V_Class","V_Vel","V_Acc","Lane_ID","Pre_Veh","Fol_Veh","Spacing","Headway"
3033,9064,633,1118847885300,42.016,377.256,6451360.093,1873080.530,19.5,8.5,2,27.90,4.29,4,3022,0,93.16,3.34
3033,9065,633,1118847885400,42.060,380.052,6451362.114,1873078.608,19.5,8.5,2,28.43,6.63,4,3022,0,93.87,3.30
3033,9066,633,1118847885500,42.122,382.924,6451364.187,1873076.613,19.5,8.5,2,29.07,6.89,4,3022,0,94.49,3.25
3033,9067,633,1118847885600,42.200,385.882,6451366.307,1873074.553,19.5,8.5,2,29.62,4.41,4,3022,0,95.04,3.21
3033,9068,633,1118847885700,42.265,388.885,6451368.490,1873072.453,19.5,8.5,2,29.93,1.57,4,3022,0,95.57,3.19

...
.
.
.
```

dataframe size is 1180598

`small_df` is the dataframe

```
small_df[(small_df['Global Time']>=1118846979200)&(small_df['Global Time'] <=1118846989200)]
```

```
TypeError: <class 'int'> type object 1118846979200
```

This is the error message I got

I wish to get 
dataframes pertaining to each 10s or 10000ms separately

Comment: runs fine on my computer. What is your python version?

Comment: python 3                                    
mintime=1118846979200
maxtime=1118846989200       small_df[(small_df['Global Time']>=mintime)&(small_df['Global Time'] <=maxtime)]                       For which I m getting TypeError